# Define Retrofit return type using interface instead of class

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Having simple Retrofit interface

```
interface Movies {
    @GET("movies/trending")
    fun trending(): Observable<List<TrendingMovie>>
}
```

Is it possible to define TrendingMovie as interface (result would be Observable emititng list of of anonymous classes implementing this interface)?

(I tried do do this, but I got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No JsonAdapter for interface com.test.TrendingMovie)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is definitely possible, but requires you to add a custom deserializer for the interface. This is done through registering a custom type deserializer for the deserializing tool you use.

With Jackson (which I would recommend to use for working with Kotlin classes, after all), this is done through adding a `Module` to the `ObjectMapper`. Here are the steps I made to do this with [`jackson-module-kotlin`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin):

1. Create a custom `Module` with a `JsonDeserializer` added for your interface:

   ```
   fun trendingMovieModule(): Module = SimpleModule().apply {
       val deserializer: JsonDeserializer<TrendingMovie> = object : JsonDeserializer<TrendingMovie>() {
           override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): TrendingMovie {
               val node = p.codec.readTree<JsonNode>(p)

               return object : TrendingMovie { // Your anonymous class here, for example:
                   val name = node["movie"]["title"]
                   val watchers = node["watchers"].intValue()

                   override fun toString(): String = "$name, watchers: $watchers"
               }
           }
       }

       addDeserializer(TrendingMovie::class.java, deserializer)
   }
   ```
2. Register the module with the `ObjectMapper` you use for the `Retrofit` builder:

   ```
   val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
           .registerModule(trendingMovieModule())
   ```
3. Use the `mapper` in the `Retrofit` builder:

   ```
   val r = Retrofit.Builder()
           // other necessary configuration omitted, e.g. custom OkHttpClient
           .baseUrl("https://api.trakt.tv")
           .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(mapper))
           .build().create(Movies::class.java)
   ```

   <sup>The `JacksonConverterFactory` requires dependency: [`converter-jackson`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-jackson).</sup>
4. Done! It should work now:

   ```
   r.trending().flatMap { Observable.from(it) }.forEach(::println)
   ```

   Complete source file: [(here)](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/462be52d8e1aca1d4b2575ef6c8cf4f2)